# How to convert value from checkbox (array) to String in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox

I make a form that have checkbox,
when the value of checkbox was store in database,
when I try to show the field of my data base in to display table (jsp),
I got this `Ljava.lang.String;@1fb8702` on the field of my checkbox value,

this is part of my jsp,

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
       id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="authority" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="authorityName" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="menu" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="sub_menu_user" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="sub_menu_monitoring" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="sub_menu_parameter" text="default text"/>
        </th>
        <th>
            <spring:message code="action" text="default text"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${requestScope.authorityuser}">
        <tr>
            <td>${row.id_authority}</td>
            <td>${row.nama_authority}</td>
            <td>${row.menu}</td>
            <td>${row.sub_menu_user}</td>
            <td>${row.sub_menu_monitoring}</td>
            <td>${row.sub_menu_parameter}</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_authority" value="${row.id_authority }">
            <td><a href="#update" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
                   class="update" id_update="${row.id_authority}"
                   nama_authority="${row.nama_authority}" menu="${row.menu}"
                   sub_menu_user="${row.sub_menu_user}" sub_menu_monitoring="${row.sub_menu_monitoring}"
                   sub_menu_parameter="${row.sub_menu_parameter}"> <i class="icon-edit"></i>
                <spring:message code="edit" text="default text"/>
            </a><a href="#delete" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
                   class="delete" id_delete="${row.id_authority}">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                <spring:message code="delete" text="default text"/>
            </a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my jps of my checkbox :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <spring:message code="authority" text="default text"/>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_authority" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <spring:message code="authorityName" text="default text"/>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nama_authority" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <spring:message code="authorityRight" text="default text"/>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="user">User<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="user1">User1
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="user2">User2
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="user3">User3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="monitoring">Monitoring<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="monitoring1">Monitoring1
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="monitoring2">Monitoring2
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="monitoring3">Monitoring3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="parameter">Parameter<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="parameter1">Parameter1
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="parameter2">Parameter2
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="parameter3">Parameter3
    </td>
</tr>
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: [How to iterate an array in JSP?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/jstl-foreach-tag-example-in-jsp-looping.html). Form a string from array and use it.

Comment: using scriplets `<% String str=java.util.Arrays.toString(array); str=str.substring(1,str.length()-1); %>`

Comment: @Braj where I've to put that scriplets??

Comment: I haven't found any check box in your posted code. Can't help.

Comment: @Braj I've add my code of checkbox, any idea??

Comment: Are you using `Struts`?

Comment: How are you retrieving the parameters from the form?

Comment: @Braj I'm using hibernate

Comment: Have a look at [Retrieving multiple textbox values with same name from JSP in Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421363/retrieving-multiple-textbox-values-with-same-name-from-jsp-in-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.getPameterValues("sub_menu_user")` will give an array of upto 3 values.

```
<td>
    <c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_user}">
        ${u}
    </c:forEach>
</td>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's work... but after the data has been edit and store to database, this is `Ljava.lang.String;@1fb8702` back again, any idea??

Comment: That is the internal short name for a String array at "address" 16b8702. No, sorry.

Comment: the `Ljava.lang.String` just happen in first checkbox after edited and the value of my first checkbox doesn't store to database . . .

Comment: Sorry I must admit I was plainly wrong (more or less) see [the jvm doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).